# How can I use version 2.2.1 of PlayFramework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.4

I want to use PlayFramework version 2.2.1, but when I run the PlayApplication, the message shown at event log is like this:

```
Play ebean module has been replaced with an external Play ebean plugin.
See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24 for details.
```

In addition, project loading failed. This document is for migration to PlayFramework version 2.4 and if I follow this instruction, I assume I am forced to use version 2.4.

Do I have any other option to follow this document?

I really want to use version 2.2.1. Nowadays nobody use the version?

Comment: Last commit is over a year ago, so I'd say 2.2 is deprecated. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.2.x

Comment: Thanks, I will keep it in my mind.

Comment: If you are starting a new application, why start it with such an old version?

Comment: There is a tiny reason, but I will start learning the latest version soon.

Comment: what version of the Play plugin do you have configured in `plugins.sbt`?